My laptop bricked after ubuntu upgrade from 22.04 -> 24.04
I bought thunderobot laptop with buildin win11 ssd (win11 with bitlocker). Then i add new ssd and install ubuntu, for year all works fine until i update the ubuntu from 22.04 to 24.04.1 LTS After finish update the system rebooted and now i can't boot to any os. I tried to boot ubuntu (all kernels in grub menu), tried recovery mode, tried windows (after enter bitlocker key it stucks), tried usb iso win11, tried usb iso ubuntu and debian (i see grub menu, after choosing it stucks). I got out CMOS battery to reset bios (the time is reseted), its not help. I cant update bios, because this bios has only one version.
When i boot to recovery mode i see last message "EFI stub: UEFI Secure Boot is enabled"
All that i can do is to read my files from ubuntu ssd by grub)))
Please help me to understand how the ubuntu update bricked my pc and how to fix it.
How i tried to boot:

When laptop starts i see the grub menu and choose "Ubuntu", then i see the logo of thunderobot and nothing happens, i waiting for 20 minutes. (usually the systems started by 30 - 60 seconds)
When laptop starts i see the grub menu and choose "Advanced options for Ubuntu" then i see the list of kernels and kernels with recovery mode. I tried to run all them. When i run recovery mode the last message i see is "EFI stub: UEFI Secure Boot is enabled"
When laptop starts i see the grub menu and choose "windows boot manager". Then bitlocker ask for key, i enter, then i see logo thunderobot and nothing happens.
Downloaded iso ubuntu and rufus to make usb installer. When start laptop i press f2 button enter to bios boot device and choose usb, then see grub menu tried to run "try run and install ubuntu", it stucks.
the same with usb iso debian
Downloaded iso win11 and rufus to make usb installer. When start laptop i press f2 button enter to bios boot device and choose usb, i see logo and it stucks


Can you access the BIOS? If so, just disable Secure Boot and reboot. Does that fix it?

i tried to disable secure boot, the same((

Please mention that in the question. Explain how you tried, and what happened.
